# Why does `npx expo start ..` tell me that I should use `npx expo start ...`

Tags: react-native, expo

**UPDATE 1** : As per the comment from @Mod3rnx I did `npm i -g expo-cli` but when I then did `npx start --dev-client` I got the same output

**UPDATE 2** I doubt if it's relevant but I am using Node Version Manager ([nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)).

---

When i run `npx expo start` I get a message that "the global expo-cli has been deprecated") and that I should use `npx expo <command>` ... seems very hard to understand why I'm told this when I'm already using `npx expo start`, can anyone explain ?

I am concerned that the message is indicative of some deeper problem with my environment.

Here's the message.

```
foo@bar:~/dev/digital-id-wallet-quarkid/agente-mobile/source$ npx expo start --dev-client
WARNING: The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17. Migrate to the new local Expo CLI: https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421.
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                           │
│   The global expo-cli package has been deprecated.                        │
│                                                                           │
│   The new Expo CLI is now bundled in your project in the expo package.    │
│   Learn more: https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421.        │
│                                                                           │
│   To use the local CLI instead (recommended in SDK 46 and higher), run:   │
│   › npx expo <command>                                                    │
│                                                                           │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The blog post cited in that error message is 404 but there's a copy of in in archive.org at https://web.archive.org/web/20221222215537/https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421 .

My environment looks like this ...

```
foo@bar:~/dev/digital-id-wallet-quarkid/agente-mobile/source$ nvm current                                                                                       
v20.11.1                                                                                                                                                        
foo@bar:~/dev/digital-id-wallet-quarkid/agente-mobile/source$ node -v                                                                                           
v20.11.1                                                                                                                                                        
foo@bar:~/dev/digital-id-wallet-quarkid/agente-mobile/source$ nvm --version                                                                                     
0.39.1                                                                                                                                                          
foo@bar:~/dev/digital-id-wallet-quarkid/agente-mobile/source$ npm --version                                                                                     
10.2.4                                                                                                                                                          
foo@bar:~/dev/digital-id-wallet-quarkid/agente-mobile/source$ lsb_release -a                                                                                    
No LSB modules are available.                                                                                                                                   
Distributor ID: Ubuntu                                                                                                                                          
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS                                                                                                                              
Release:        20.04                                                                                                                                           
Codename:       focal
```

Comment: @Mod3rnx - thank you for your response. I did `npm i -g expo-cli` but when I then did `npx start --dev-client` I got the same output, that is telling me to use `npx start ...`. I'm going to update the question to reference your suggestion. Thanks again.

Comment: my bad i've copied the wrong command, that did a global install, you have to uninstall it now and try via npx again  
`npm uninstall -g expo-cli`

Comment: @Mod3mx thanks again. I did try the revised command and then the `npx expo start --dev-client` but unfortunately I still got the same, rather confusing, message. Would be interested to hear any further suggestions, thank you.

Comment: That's weird, could you check if the installation still persists, look at the output of this command `npm -g list --depth=0`, that will list all your global dependencies